# Undefined behaviour of sub-expressions

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Does this result in undefined behaviour because the order of evaluation will be unspecified?

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
int result = i++ + ++j + k++;
```

Comment: The order of evaluation is fairly clear here. Pre and post increment happen without problem.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, you're right. The order is not clear. The result is.

Comment: @Oli Your question is a duplicate as well :P http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16135 - but in this case the question is actually different as it's different variables, not the same.

Comment: I am 99.999% certain that this question is about to get closed as a dup of something that it's _not_ a dup of.

Comment: @Tomalak: I think it's becoming instinct now for most of us.  If I see ++ twice or more in a single line, my mouse cursor instinctively goes for the close button.  Luckily I saw your comment first.

Comment: @Benjamin: Exactly. I think it's an instinct that certain people ought to learn to curb, because in cases like this it has the potential to be damagingly wrong. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the result of the evaluation doesn't depend on the unspecified order of evaluation of the sub-expressions.

*Undefined behavior* only occurs in this situation if two side effects that affect the same object are unsequenced relative to each other or a side effect and a value computation of the same object are unsequenced. The side-effect and value computation of both prefix and postfix increment are explicitly sequenced.

Answer (score 4):

The order of evaluation *is* unspecified, but who cares? Each operand acts on a completely distinct object. Nothing undefined here.

Comment: I am still in the camp of "who cares". This kind of question is completely meaningless (apart from the academic exercise) as code such as this will not get past code review.

Comment: @Tux-D: There's an "understanding" element.

Answer (score 1):

No, the behavior is perfectly well-defined: `j` is incremented, then addition is performed, then `i` and `k` are incremented. The only thing that is unspecified is the order in which the increments on `i` and `k` are performed. The postcondition is `i==1`, `j==1`, `k==1`, `result==1`.

Comment: No, that sequence isn't guaranteed, the compiler is perfectly free to generate `t1 = i+1; result = t1 + j + k; ++j; ++k; i = t1;`  There's only the one sequence point, at the end of the expression.

Comment: Arrgh, swap `i` with `j` in my earlier comment.  My point stands though.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that the results are unspecified if you modify a variable more than once. You haven't done that in your example.

Comment: Not just unspecified (the compiler does not need to document which of the allowed behaviours is selected), the result is undefined (there is no limit on the possible allowed behaviours).

Answer (score 0):

It's fine here because you don't use the same variable twice.

What you have is equivalent to:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
++j;
int result = i + j + k;
++i;
++k;
```

If you were to have instead `int result = i++ + ++i + i++;` then you'd have a problem because the order of the increments is unspecified, and you depend on that order.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not the case. The evaluation order is not specified. Yes, `j`'s new value will go into the expression, and `i` and `k`'s old values, but aside from that...

Comment: No, it's not equivalent.  The original has a lot fewer sequence points.

Comment: I didn't say it was identical. It is equivalent, i.e. it has the same end result.

Comment: @Peter: It may have different behavior, when observed from another thread (or signal handler, etc).  The order in which the results become visible is completely unspecified.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: How do you plan on observing local variables from another thread?

Comment: @Peter: With [`GetThreadContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679362.aspx) or similar.  Besides, with such a small snippet of code, you can't tell whether those variables are local, member, or global.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What *is* clear from the small snippet of code is that he or she is only concerned with the value of result and whether or not undefined behaviour occurs. I don't see why you are complicating matters by conjuring up esoteric scenarios where people are reading local variables from other threads and depending on sequence points.

Answer (score 0):

Here result will be always 1. The values of j, k, and i will be all 1. Also, note that separator for several variable declaration is `,`, and not `;`:

```
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
```

Comment: And, more importantly, you won't open a black hole by executing this program... which is what the question is _really_ about.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a classic/well known c++ sequence point issue, see link here for much more detail
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int result = i++ + ++j + k++;
```

Is Equivalent too:

```
<SP>
(a1)int t1 = i;     // i++ part one: The result of post-increment is the original value
(a2)     i = i + 1; // i++ part two: the increment part separated from the result
(b1)     j = j + 1;
(b2)int t2 = j;     // The result of pre-increment is the new value
(c1)int t3 = k;     // k++ part one: The result of post-increment is the original value
(c2)     k = k + 1;
(d) int t4 = t1 + t2;
(e) int t5 = t3 + t4;    
(f) int result = t5;
<SP>
```

The constraints are:

```
(a1) is before (a2)
(a1) is before (d)
(b1) is before (b2)
(b2) is before (d) 
(c1) is before (c2)
(c1) is before (e)
(d)  is before (e)
(e)  is before (f)
```

As long as the above constraints are maintained the instructions can be re-ordered as much as the compiler likes. But the constraints guarantee that the result is well formed.